# @QuerydslPredicate with @EmbeddedId

Tags: spring, querydsl

I have an endpoint in which im using @QueryDslPredicate to bind HTTP parameters, but the root or class that im using to bind the parameters has an Embedded id and im trying to search with one of the id-s that are in the compound id that i created. For example:

```
    @Embeddable
    public class QueryDslRoot{
    
         @EmbeddedId
         private CoumpoundId compoundId;

    }
 

    @Embeddable
    public class CoumpoundId {
    
         @Column(name = "first_id")
         private String firstId;

         @Column(name = "second_id")
         priavet String secondId;
    }
```

When im calling endpoint as this :

```
localhost:8080/test?secondId={id value}
```

it doesn't bind parameter at all.

Is it possible to bind parameter with on of the variables of embeddedId if yes can you show me how ??

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

=================>  FIX IS HERE : <===================

Fixed it :

To be able to bind the parameter u simply use ?compoundid{dot}{variableId} for example:

localhost:8080/test?compoundId.secondId={id value}